# Java: How do I change my audio output device from the default?

Tags: java, audio, mixer, freetts

So I'm working with text to speech. I need to have it play out on a specific line (over my tv instead of over the default headphones).

I managed to read the devices and grab the correct line with

```
static void printAllMixerNames() {
    for(Mixer.Info info : AudioSystem.getMixerInfo()) {
        System.out.println(info.getName());
    }
}
```

but how do I actually set which line to play over?

Thanks!

EDIT* I'm working with FreeTTS